# Do special procedures exist for commercial pilots flying over Russia?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radar, commercial-operations, russia

Since Russia, and in particular the Asian part of it, is huge, I was wondering if there are special procedures for commercial pilots to follow over Russia (in particular and specifically Siberia and other sparsely populated parts)? (Except that they use the metric system.)

Does Russia provide radar coverage and flight following services over its entire territory? As an example, do the use procedures like the North Atlantic Tracks, or do pilots implement their "own ATC" by stating position reports regularly, just like over some parts of Africa?

Or is flying over Russia comparable to flying over any other European / U.S. / ... country with continued ATC service?

Answer (score 3):

> > Does Russia provide radar coverage and flight following services over its entire territory?

Not all countries publish the exact radar coverage, as it is sensitive information. But, if the flight over Russia is IFR (controlled), then the answer is yes, regardless of the remoteness of the area.

The services and limitations can be found in any country's AIP, and the Russian AIP is [publicly available](http://www.caiga.ru/common/AirInter/validaip/html/eng.htm). By checking [GEN 3.3](http://www.caiga.ru/common/AirInter/validaip/aip/gen/gen3/1-gen3-3.pdf):

> 1.3 Radar service is provided at all phases of control service indicated in para 1.2.

and 1.2 basically covers all phases of controlled flight:

> 1.2 The air traffic control service is divided into:
>
> a) area control service - the provision of control service for flights of all aircraft in CTA (FIR/СТА), except those indicated below in items b) and c);
>
> b) approach control service - the provision of control service connected with arrival and departure of all aircraft;
>
> c) aerodrome control service - the provision of control service to aerodrome traffic, except that indicated in item b).

Comment: so basically, ATC-wise, flying over Russia's remote areas is no different than anywhere else?

Comment: @Stefan - Correct, that's what's meant by *radar service.*